# angular: ngrx effects not firing

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I've worked on a few Angular apps that implemented Redux (NgRx).
I can't figure out my current project's issue.

Actions:

```
export class GetUserFromStorage implements Action {
  readonly type = UserActionTypes.GetUserFromStorage;
}

export class GetUserFromStorageSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = UserActionTypes.GetUserFromStorageSuccess;
  constructor(public payload: User | null) { }
}

export class GetUserFromStorageFail implements Action {
  readonly type = UserActionTypes.GetUserFromStorageFail;
  constructor(public payload: string) { }
}
```

Reducer:

```
case UserActionTypes.GetUserFromStorageSuccess:
    return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        error: ''
    };

case UserActionTypes.GetUserFromStorageFail:
    return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload
    };
```

Effects:

```
@Effect() getUserFromStorage$:
Observable<userActions.GetUserFromStorageSuccess | userActions.GetUserFromStorageFail>
    = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(userActions.UserActionTypes.GetUserFromStorage),
        tap(() => console.log('GETUserToStorage$', )),
        mergeMap((action: userActions.GetUserFromStorage) =>
            this.storageService.getItem(StorageKeys.USER).pipe(
                map((user: User | null) =>
                    new userActions.GetUserFromStorageSuccess(user)),
                catchError((error: string) =>
                    of(new userActions.GetUserFromStorageFail(error)))
                ))
            );
```

In the auth.service.ts I subscribe to the Store and I dispatch some Actions.

```
this.store.dispatch(new userActions.GetUserFromStorage());

this.store.pipe(select(userReducer.getUser)).subscribe(
    (user: User) => {
        console.log('user TEST: ', user);
        this.user = user;
    }
);
```

I have ReduxDevTools installed.
The GetUserFromStorage action fires, but it doesn't trigger the getUserFromStorage$ effect.
The console.logged value of 'user TEST' shows that the 'user' is 'null'.
Any ideas, anybody?
Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make sure you have actually "activated" them.

Effects injectable:

```
@Injectable()

export class FooEffects {

  @Effect() getUserFromStorage$:
Observable<userActions.GetUserFromStorageSuccess | userActions.GetUserFromStorageFail>
    = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(userActions.UserActionTypes.GetUserFromStorage),
        tap(() => console.log('GETUserToStorage$', )),
        mergeMap((action: userActions.GetUserFromStorage) =>
            this.storageService.getItem(StorageKeys.USER).pipe(
                map((user: User | null) =>
                    new userActions.GetUserFromStorageSuccess(user)),
                catchError((error: string) =>
                    of(new userActions.GetUserFromStorageFail(error)))
                ))
            );
}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import {EffectsModule} from '@ngrx/effects';

imports: [
  EffectsModule.forRoot([
    FooEffects
  ])
]
```

Comment: if you saw the face-palm I've just face-palmed myself with...you'd cry... Thanks so much!

Comment: Been there :-) Glad it helped!

Comment: answer still applicable ngrx ^8.6.0 and 9. Alternatively `EffectsModule.forFeature()`

Comment: for dynamically feature module, you have to make sure that the effect is loaded in the current modules. Add the effect to the current module will fix the issue.