# NgRx logout effect not firing

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I've created a small application that permits a user to login and logout using ngrx state. The user login works well. I can login and using an AuthGuard I can check if the user is still login in the app after the refresh of the page. Now I should logout the user. This is my action:

```
export const LOGOUT = '[Auth] Logout';
export const logout = createAction(
    LOGOUT
  );
```

than the effect

```
logout$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$
            .pipe(
                ofType(userActions.logout),
                tap(action => {
                    localStorage.removeItem('user');
                    this.router.navigate(['login']);
                })
            )
    ,{dispatch: false});
```

and of ourse the reducer:

```
export const authReducer = createReducer (
    defaultUser,

    on(userActions.logout, (state, action) => {
        return {
            user: undefined
        }
    })
)
```

After that, I can create in my component a logout button with this

```
onLogout(){
    this.store.dispatch(logout())
  }
```

I expect that the dispatch call the action and then the effect. Inside the effect it should remove the user from the localStorage. but even if I try to debug the effect it doesn't enter inside the tap operator. It doesn't remove the item and it doesn't redirect to login. Is there anything else i missed here?

Comment: Have you added the effects class to EffectsModule.forRoot()/forFeature() in your module?

Comment: @AkshayRana you saved me. Thank you. I forgot to add it to my module.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular: ngrx effects not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592589/angular-ngrx-effects-not-firing)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [official doc](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#registering-root-effects),

> After you've written your Effects class, you must register it so the
>   effects start running. To register root-level effects, add the
>   `EffectsModule.forRoot()` method with an array of your effects to your
>   `AppModule`.

If in this case, the `effect` module is called `AuthEffect`, we should have this code snippet in `AppModule`:

```js
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { AuthEffects } from './effects/auth.effects';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.forRoot([ AuthEffects ])
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If authentication is managed inside a [feature module](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#register-feature-state), you should use in place this code, to register `AuthEffect` inside `AuthModule`:

```js
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { AuthEffects } from './effects/auth.effects';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.forFeature([ AuthEffects ])
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```