# How to dynamically register a ngrx effect?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

**Quickly**

I am trying to dynamically create a ngrx effect.

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

I want to be able to dispatch actions in my ngrx store and then be able to decide what to do when the action is a success or a failure.

**How I am doing it (for now):**

I have 3 Actions in my store. `LOAD_DOCUMENT`, `LOAD_DOCUMENT_SUCCESS` and `LOAD_DOCUMENT_FAILURE`. For now, I'm trying to create an `Observable` from the `Actions` that listen on `LOAD_DOCUMENT_SUCCESS` and `LOAD_DOCUMENT_FAILURE`. When either of them is dispatched, it will call the `processPostAction()` method. Once the Observable is ready, I call the `LOAD_DOCUMENT` Action.

**Here is my implementation:**

```
@Injectable()
export class DispatchHandlerProcessor<STORE_STATE> {

  actions$: Observable<Action>[] = [];

  constructor(
    private _store: Store<STORE_STATE>,
    private _dispatchedActions: Actions
  ) { } 

  process<SUCC extends Action, FAIL extends Action>(handler: DispatchHandler<SUCC, FAIL>): void {
    const postActionProcessor$: Observable<Action>
      = this._dispatchedActions.pipe(
        ofType(handler.successType, handler.failureType), // Either LOAD_DOCUMENT_SUCCESS or LOAD_DOCUMENT_FAILURE
        tap((action: SUCC | FAIL) => {
          handler.processPostAction(action); // method executed after LOAD_DOCUMENT
      })
    );
    this.actions$.push(postActionProcessor$);
    this._store.dispatch(handler.actionToDispatch); // call LOAD_DOCUMENT
  }

}
```

**The current behaviour:**

Currently:

- the `process()` method is called.
- An Observable is created for the effect and added to the array.
- The `LOAD_DOCUMENT` Action is called and ends with a `LOAD_DOCUMENT_SUCCESS`
- **The effect created in the `process(...)` method in never called**
- So I guess: The effect is not registered (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592589/angular-ngrx-effects-not-firing))

**My questions:**

How can I dynamically register my effect? Is there a better way to achieve the pattern I am trying to implement?

**Small notes:** The actions array is going to grow and create memory issues. For now it is just a small hack to get it working. Ideally, I would like to register the effect rather than use this array.

I also realised the `@Effect` keyword wasn't placed anywhere. I have an error `Decorators are not valid here` when placing it line 12.

All my effects 'normally' created are running perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I resolved it using a subscription to the `Actions`.

Here is the code:

```
@Injectable()
export class DispatchHandlerProcessor<STORE_STATE> {

  constructor(
    private _store: Store<STORE_STATE>,
    private _dispatchedActions: Actions
  ) { } 

  process<SUCC extends Action, FAIL extends Action>(handler: DispatchHandler<SUCC, FAIL>): void {
    const subscription: Subscription = this._dispatchedActions.subscribe(action => {
      if(action.type == handler.successType || action.type == handler.failureType) {
        handler.processPostAction(<SUCC | FAIL>action);
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    });
    this._store.dispatch(handler.actionToDispatch);
  }
}
```

I'm still interested in how to dynamically register `@Effect` if someone knows the answer though!

Comment: I'm interested in doing something like this, to share one store between multiple angular micro applications in the same page. Have you found a way of registering an effect dynamically ?

Comment: Hi manu, no, I didn't find a way to do so. We ended up using the solution up there.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to register the NgRx Effects service dynamically (not on the routing level) by using the class [EffectSources](https://ngrx.io/api/effects/EffectSources) method addEffects.
But you must pass an instance of effect service class as an argument, not the class itself.

```
constructor(
   private readonly _effectSources: EffectSources,
   private readonly _effects: Effects,
) {
   _effectSources.addEffects(effects);
}
```

And you also need to provide EffectService somehow (providedIn: "root" is probably the easiest option.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class Effects {

}
```